# Should rice be started in cold or boiling water?

Tags: rice, water

There are two main methods, either putting the rice into water already at boiling point, or putting them in cold water and then putting on the heat.

Which method is the best to cook rice?

Does it make a difference if you add rice to cold or boiling water?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't make much difference. A few things to consider and also why I use cold water.

- Once you bring the water to a boil you need to turn  it down to a simmer. Adding cold rice at this point can thriw off this process.
- Rice is typically cooked based on ratios of volume. Boiling the water first won't effect this *unless* you lose track of it and the boiling causes your water content to reduce.
- Lastly rice cookers these days are set-and-forget and boiling the water first is an unnecessary step.

All in all boiling your water first is not a problem but doesn't add any value.

Answer (score -2):

the second method is better than first because it's enhanced the taste of rice and rice become larger than its original size.
     if you cook biryani its good to put rice first into cold water than in putting hot water due to this look of biryani was very awesome.